# Overscan margin on Android TV

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I'm modifying the existing application to work on Android TV with a ADT-1 Developer Kit.
The outside edge of the original application layout when installing on Android TV is clipped.
Then I followed [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html) and set the overscan for the root of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/base_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" >
  .....
</LinearLayout>
```

But the result is like below.
The root of layout is margin so much, it doesn't fill the screen (the area in red rectangle).
What is the pixel of overscan margin for the root layout to fill exactly the screen? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. By setting the margin to the root layout, you are obviously getting a smaller screen estate to display your content. What would you like to obtain?

Comment: If I don't set margin, the outside edge layout is clipped. I want to know what is the exact pixel to set the margin to the root layout, so that my content can fill the screen and don't be clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct margin, **because it depends on your TV**.

Some TVs will *enlarge the picture* (say, those with a non-so-standard aspect ratio) so that it will fit the screen, some others will *leave the picture as is*.

You are hence adding a 10% margin to your layout, to make sure it will **always** be visible. Using px instead of dp will make little to no difference.

Comment: If it's true, It's so inconvenient. We have to calculate 10% margin and set margin for every root layout manually.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html#structure. I don't know why they suggest dp instead of px.

Comment: Because some TVs will have a 720p resolution and some others will go for a 1080p, probably. Anyway, if you use the standard UI widgets that come with the Leanback library, those margins are already added.

Comment: I have one more question. How can some UI widgets in the Leanback library can flexibly set oversan margin with different TV devices?? I plugged ADT-1 Developer Kit into different TV devices. Some apps using Leanback UI widgets always fill up the screen.

Comment: They are not "adaptive", if that's what you mean. If you want to take a look yourself, this is the dimens.xml for the Leanback library, which defines the margin for `BrowseFragment`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v17/leanback/res/values/dimens.xml?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F

Comment: I looked at dimens.xml and BroweFragment file before. But I can't find which margin is used to set the margin of BrowseFragment.

Answer (score 3):

If the TV does not provide overscan settings in system settings (just like mine sony android TV), you can fix it via shell:

```
adb connect 192.168.0.100
adb shell wm overscan reset
```

If the reset does not do what expected, use LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM values in pixels

```
adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,0
adb shell wm overscan 10,20,30,40
```

Comment: Those commands will not affect the physical TV overscan. By default they will be 0,0,0,0. If you manage to modify those to match your physical overscan it will squeeze image to fit into viewable area, but it will be by means of double-overscan.